Seting alias problems
PS C:\Users\goose> get-alias rtl

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           rtl -> Get-ChildItem


PS C:\Users\goose> set-alias  rtl -Value gci | Sort-Object LastAccessTime
PS C:\Users\goose> get-alias rtl

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           rtl -> Get-ChildItem

I've tried all sort of combos to set that alias to the fuller version. No matter what I do it is reverting to gci. It's not defined in $profile. What am I doing wrong?

not what Set-Alias is meant for. Create a function instead.

New-Alias isn't working for me, even after Remove-Item Alias:rtl  Nothing could be further from my mind than "referencing an alias as a variable". My intention is to create an alias and make it stick

Set-Alias ONLY works for the base cmdlet.
You CANNOT use it to call parameters or more complex commands.

No parameters involved in my command

actually there is: the implied -Property parameter of Sort-Object. But piping already covers the "more complex" part.

So, effectively you can't pipe into an alias?

Sure you can: Resolve-Path .\ | gci works perfectly. But you cannot make an alias of a pipeline. An alias is EXCLUSIVELY an alternate writing of the cmdlet\function name. It cannot contains parameters, variables, pipelines etc

Oh yes, I see now. You mean you can't have a pipeline in the alias. I still don't know where rtl has been defined though and how to track that down
